# Visual Studio Code: How to open a local file in a remote session via its path?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am working on Windows with a remote SSH session to a Linux environment in Visual Studio Code. Sometimes I want to open a local file from my Windows system in this session.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to open a file, Visual Studio Code offers me a button "Show local", which opens a file browser on my local computer to search a file:

[image]

Unfortunately it's not possible to enter my file path directly (say `c:\myfile.txt`). Obviously in remote setups only remote paths can be entered.

Is there some syntax or extension I can use to directly enter a local file path, without needing to open the file browser?

Comment: I opened an issue for this topic: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136218

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136218) I got a solution for this. Use the following setting:

```
"files.simpleDialog.enable": true
```

This does not open the native file browser on "Show local". Instead, you can search for the local file in the same manner as you would do for remote files:

[image: local file picker]